# how do I remove in text file a specific range of number and words?

Tags: bash

I have a file like this:

```
Coffee
3
chocolate
4,5
fish
2
tomatoes
6
```

and so on...

I want using bash to delete in this file all number higher then 4.

Output like this

```
Coffee
3
fish
2
```

is it possible using sed or awk?

Answer (score 2):

With awk

```
awk 'NR%2==1{a=$0}$0<=4{print a RS $0}' infile
```

Comment: I have another file.txt                                                                                          meat
fish
coffee
eggs
out_put: meet,fish [3.4,5.6,7.8]
END
tea
carrots
bread
out_put: tea,carrots [4.5,6.7]
END

would like

meat
fish
coffee
eggs
out_put: meet,fish [3.4] meat,coffee [5.6] meet,eggs [7.8] or meat,fish meat,coffee meat,eggs[3.4,5.6,7.8]
END
tea
carrots
bread
out_put: tea,carrots [4.5] tea,bread [6.7] or tea,carrots tea,bread [4.5,6.7]    is it possible with sed/awk?

Comment: It' difficult to read your new request in comment. You can edit the question if it's nearly the same or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

It might be as easy doing it in `bash` :

```
while read -r product; do
  read -r quantity
  if [[ "$quantity" > 4 ]]; then
    echo $product
    echo $quantity
  fi
done < yourInputFile
```